# How to set permission for Folder in Blackberry ?

Tags: blackberry

I want to know how to set permission for  folder that is created by my app so no one can delete or see that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not 100% possible, however you may do smth in this direction. Check for [FileConnection.setHidden(boolean)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#setHidden%28boolean%29), [FileConnection.setWritable(boolean)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#setWritable%28boolean%29) and  [FileConnection.setReadable(boolean)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#setReadable%28boolean%29).

First of all, the API docs are vague as to whether those methods will have any effect at all on a specific device (meaning a file system).

Secondly, even if you use [FileConnection.setHidden(boolean)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#setHidden%28boolean%29), then it is still possible for another app to "see" your file/dir by using [FileConnection.list(String filter, boolean includeHidden)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#list%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29). Once one has a path of you hidden dir, he/she can change the hidden attr (and other attrs), so it becomes visible/readable/killable.

Comment: Hi Arhimed thanks for reply & can v encrypt particular  folder?

Comment: If you are talking about whether it's possible to encrypt the contents of the files, then yes, of course, this is possible. Check the "Encrypting and decrypting data using factories" as a starting point - http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21091/Encrypting_and_decrypting_using_factories_1304691_11.jsp